# Finding out power requirements for plug replacement

Tags: mains, plug

I bought a inverter for arc welding that is imported and comes with a [CEE 7/7 plug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schuko) (I guess it goes to the European market). In Brazil we have two [types of plugs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AC_power_plugs_and_sockets#IEC_60906-1_.28Brazilian_NBR.C2.A014136.29_.28Type_N.29) one for 10A and another for 20A (they differ in plug diameter).

Now the manual for the inverter says that the Imax is 27.8A. In the power supply specification section it says that the cables are 1.5 mm2 and the line current is 10.8 A. The plug that came with the inverter was rated for 16A.

Now, I would rather use a 10A brazilian plug, as it is more ubiquitous and convenient. Can I do that or should I step up and use the 20A plug, and thus limiting the places where I can plug the inverter?

Comment: What are the fuses for these 10A plugs?

Comment: Don't really know. I would have to open the inverter to take a look, but the section that I mentioned is called "Recommended fuses and power cable", it doesn't mention a specific number for the fuses, just "Line current I1eff: 10,8A", anything else would be just a guess.

Comment: @johnfound, are you talking about those plugs with a fuse inside? Never saw them, they aren't used in Brazil, here we use just circuit breakers and only devices have internal fuses, nothing else. I thought you mentioned the fuse of the inverter.

Comment: I mean "sockets" actually. In every electro installation there is a shield with fuses - for the sockets, for the lamps and so on.

Comment: In Brazil, code says that sockets are arranged in circuits and every circuit must have a circuit breaker with the ratet capacity for the circuit (along with cables of same capacity). Specific devices that are more demanding (dry washers, microwaves, eletric ovens, etc) should each be in a separate circuit with a dedicated breaker. Breakers for a run of sockets rated for 10A are around 16A to 30A depending on the number of sockets in the run.

Comment: So, 10A sockets have 10A circuit breakers?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11074/discussion-between-luiz-borges-and-johnfound)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now, after some comments, my answer. The main problem of using 10A plug is not the current itself, because it can withstand a lot more current for a short period of time, but the circuit breakers (or fuses) in the main shield of the electrical installation.

After some conversation with the asker it becomes clear that in Brazil, the rated current of the circuit breakers depend on the count of the sockets connected in this circuit and 30A is not uncommon value.

So, my answer is: Yes, the inverter will work without any problems with 10A plug. There is no need to use rare special sockets.

Comment: Just found out a [spec sheet](http://www.esab.co.uk/gb/en/support/upload/BuddyArc-145_UKpdf.pdf) for the welder that says the fuse which is used by it: 16A slow. So I guess I'm fine with a 10A plug.